# Set item active depending on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got several links on the top of my content area.
They should get the `active` class based on the url.

For example:
If the URL is `/Products/Materials/Glass` the `Glass` link should be active.

Basically this works with my actual code but it also sets the `all` link active, which should only be active when the url is for example `/Products/Materials`. Notice the value after `/Products` changes

Screenshot:
[image]

[image]

**Here is my Code:**

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="category-filter-item">
        <a class="js-subcategory-link subcategory-link">
            <span>All<span>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-filter-item">
        <a class="js-subcategory-link subcategory-link">
            <span>Wood<span>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-filter-item">
        <a class="js-subcategory-link subcategory-link">
            <span>Glass<span>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-filter-item">
        <a class="js-subcategory-link subcategory-link">
            <span>Metal<span>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-filter-item">
        <a class="js-subcategory-link subcategory-link">
            <span>Concrete<span>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-filter-item">
        <a class="js-subcategory-link subcategory-link">
            <span>Stone<span>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function setItemActive(){
    var path = window.location.pathname;

    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);


    $('.js-subcategory-link').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if(path.substring(0,href.length) === href){
            $(this).closest('div').addClass('category-filter-item-active');
            $(this).children('.arrow').addClass('arrow-category');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Does this `category-filter-item-active` class sets a div as active?

Comment: Yes, category-filter-item-active sets the div as active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a specific if in for the all link:

```js
function setItemActive(path) {
  // var path = window.location.pathname;

  path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
  path = decodeURIComponent(path);


  $('.js-subcategory-link').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if ((this.id === "alle-link" && path.match(/\//g).length <= 2) || 
    (this.id !== "alle-link" && path.startsWith(href)))
    {
      $(this).closest('div').addClass('category-filter-item-active');
      $(this).children('.arrow').addClass('arrow-category');
    }

  });
}

setItemActive('/Product/category/subcategory-1');
```

```css
.category-filter-item-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="/Product" class="js-subcategory-link" id="alle-link">All</a></div>
<div><a href="/Product/category/subcategory-1" class="js-subcategory-link">subcategory 1</a></div>
<div><a href="/Product/category/subcategory-2" class="js-subcategory-link">subcategory 2</a></div>
<div><a href="/Product/category/subcategory-3" class="js-subcategory-link">subcategory 3</a></div>
<div><a href="/Product/category/subcategory-4" class="js-subcategory-link">subcategory 4</a></div>
<div><a href="/Product/category/subcategory-5" class="js-subcategory-link">subcategory 5</a></div>
```

Comment: I made a little mistake in my question, the all link should be active when the user is 1 level after products. So it's /Products/Category/Subcategory. The links are only displayed in the /Category section. So the tricky thing is that the URL after /Products is changing, depending on which category the user selects. I hope i could explain it well^^

Comment: Can you add an id to your all link?   If so I would do the above.  If you have multiple all links then you can use a unique class for them and use `hasClass()` to check instead of the `this.id === ` in the if

Comment: Yessss! Now it works! :D Thank you so much you saved my day twice! Now i can rest in peace haha ;-)

Comment: Hahaha, nice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var storedListItem = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedListItem');
    $("ul.nav > li > a:eq("+(storedListItem)+")").addClass("active");
    $("ul.nav > li").on("click",function(){
        var index = $(this).index('ul.nav > li');
        var selectedListItem = index;
        sessionStorage.setItem('selectedListItem', JSON.stringify(selectedListItem));
    });
```

When you click a list item in the menu the index of that list item is stored, it is then saved in session storage. One the page refreshes it is retrieved then the active class is added to that item index. Showing the page as active. It resolves the question because it adds the active class after the page is loaded thus actually showing it as active, the answers above would not do that.

Comment: This wouldn't work for cases where people came directly to the page of a sub section

Comment: couldnt you added to it to catch that?

Comment: But then you would be checking the url again and therefore you may as well do it in the original way

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove active class before adding active class to any div. So it will resolve you problem.

```
    function setItemActive(){
        var path = window.location.pathname;

        path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
        path = decodeURIComponent(path);


        $('.js-subcategory-link').each(function(){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            if(path.substring(0,href.length) === href){
                $('.js-subcategory-link').removeClass('category-filter-item-active'); 
// It removes active class from all divs then it assigns to particular div
                $(this).closest('div').addClass('category-filter-item-active');
                $(this).children('.arrow').addClass('arrow-category');
            }
        })
    }
```